# Unable to Receive messaging_referrals Events Despite Proper Webhook Configuration for Messenger Webhook API Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-webhooks, facebook-messages

I'm facing an issue with my Facebook Messenger app where I'm unable to receive messaging_referrals events despite having configured my webhook permissions correctly.

Here's what I've done so far:

I've created a Facebook app for my Messenger bot.

In the app settings, under "Messenger Settings," I've set up a webhook with a publicly accessible callback URL, and I've specified a Verify Token for authentication.

In the webhook subscription fields, I've selected "messaging_referrals" to ensure I receive these events.

I've implemented a webhook server in my Java Spring application to handle incoming POST requests, including the messaging_referrals events.

[image]
Despite these configurations and code, I'm still not receiving messaging_referrals events when I click the test button or send referral links to my bot.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or could provide insights into what might be missing or misconfigured in my setup? Any guidance on troubleshooting this issue would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I should mention that other events like 'messages' and 'messaging_postbacks' are being successfully received by my webhook and handled as expected. It's only the messaging_referrals events that seem to be problematic.

Comment: Watching this question, we're experiencing the same in our app.

Comment: Same problem here :(

Comment: I can't even get the regular "messages" webhook to fire...